# Custom connector fails inside the flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, soap, custom-connector

I have a custom connector created using PostMan 2.1 Collection/Swagger definition.
The connector works fine when configuring and testing.

[image]

When you save this connector and use it inside a flow, it fails with an error that the browser sent a request in a different format the server was expecting data in a different format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the 'Show raw inputs' to view all the request headers that are being sent to the connector?

If so, maybe you can reproduce the error in PostMan by adding all those headers, and eliminating one-by-one to see which header is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Paul!

I purchased a flow premium license and simply used the HTTP call in it, and got over with it. This was too bad to troubleshoot.